# I get this error "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" while trying to execute my code

Tags: python, file, directory, zip, compression

My teacher tasked us to write a program that compacts the elements of a directory that is given to it by keyboard and stores it in a “vardir” variable (example: vardir = ”c: \ windows”), take the directory files and generate in a compact file in the windows desktop, setting it as the file name "resp" plus the name of the day of the week, plus the week number of the current year of the system.

```
   from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import zipfile
import os
import shutil

weekday = "%A"
weeknumber = "%W"
yearnumber = "%j"
today = date.today()
day = today.strftime(weekday)
week = today.strftime(weeknumber)
year = today.strftime(yearnumber)

name= "" + day+week+year

vardir = "C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\Misceláneo\Roncones"

place = 'C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\'+name+".zip"

comprimir=zipfile.ZipFile(place,'w')

with zipfile.ZipFile(vardir+name.upper()+".zip", "w") as zipObj:
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(vardir):
        for filename in filenames:
            filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
            zipObj.write(filePath)
print("Compresión completa")
```

---

```
File "<ipython-input-4-42fc3b06823e>", line 19
    place = 'C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\'+name+".zip"
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you are setting your `place` variable, you did not escape the `\` character.  Because of that, the `\` at the end of your string is causing the closing `'` to be escaped, therefore not closing the string.

Something you can do about it is escape the `\` character like this:

```py
place = 'C:\\Users\\wuise\\Desktop\\'+name+".zip"
# look at the code highlighting: this is not green like the string
```

This prevents the `\` character from escaping the `'` character.

In your question, the comment would be green:

```py
place = 'C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\'+name+".zip"
# this is green because it is part of the above string
```